# javascript how to get the program to react to a mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm making an interactive clock animation, where normally the clock just does its thing and is a clock. The interactive part comes in when the user clicks the mouse anywhere on the screen and the clock resets itself to where it began. Where would I add an event listener since I'm not using any buttons to accomplish this? Essentially I want the element to be the whole screen, without turning it into a button (for visual purposes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the document's `<body>` extends to the width and height of the browser's window, which I assume is the case with your site, then... **You could just do:**

```
document.body.onclick = function () {
    ...
};
```

**Or**

```
function stopTheTimer() {
    ...
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', stopTheTimer);
```

Since all of your visible HTML is inside of the body tag, then effectively, all that is visible inside of the browser window will respond to that click event.

---

If you aren't sure, or if the body tag doesn't fill up the whole window's space, you can attach the listener to the `document`, which is the element that contains all of the HTML (including the body). **So you would do:**

```
document.onclick = function () {
    ...
};
```

**Or**

```
document.addEventListener('click', stopTheTimer);
```

---

The first example allows you to only add one listener of the same type at once, while the second one allows for multiple listeners of the same type.

You can also attach the listener to the `window` object, but that doesn't work in < IE8, so you're better off using either `document` or `body`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the listener to `document.body` if that's the nearest parent to the clock markup, but it seems cleaner to just wrap the clock markup in a `div` and give it an ID of "clock", so you can more easily reference it. Then, the click handler works just like any other:

```
    var clock = document.getElementById('clock'); 
    clock.onclick = function(event) {
      window.location.reload(); // or whatever you want to do
    };
```